# Why build_runner watch command is not working?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-build

I have this flutter project I've been working on and I need code generation for various reasons, such as riverpod providers and freezed models. So I'm using `build_runner` package to generate this `.g.dart` files, but suddenly when I run `dart run build_runner watch` I'm getting this error:

```
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 152ms
[WARNING] ../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_generator-3.0.0-dev.4/lib/src/templates/family.dart:230:48: Error: The getter 'metadata' isn't defined for the class 'AstNode'.
 - 'AstNode' is from 'package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart' ('../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/analyzer-6.2.0/lib/src/dart/ast/ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'metadata'.
    final meta = metaAnnotations(provider.node.metadata);
                                               ^^^^^^^^
[INFO] Precompiling build script... completed, took 625ms
[SEVERE] Failed to precompile build script .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart.
This is likely caused by a misconfigured builder definition.
```

I have seen several post regarding this issue but any of the suggested answers seems to work.
So I have tried several things:
`dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`
Delete `pubspec.lock` file `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`
Upgrade packages to latest versions with `flutter pub upgrade`
Adding the `analyzer` dependency package as suggested in one post.
Tried `dart run build_runner doctor` but got the same output.
I also tried `flutter chache repair` and `flutter pub get` and delete manually the cache stored int`.dart_tool/` directory but nothing is working.
I've been stuck in this for hours with no avail, and I've no idea what might be wrong.
Here's my `pubscpec.yaml` file

```
name: myapp
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: none
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.5 <4.0.0'
  flutter: ">=3.0.0"
  
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.3.6
  riverpod_annotation: ^2.2.0
  analyzer:
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  riverpod_generator: ^3.0.0-dev.3
  riverpod_lint: ^2.3.0
  build_runner: ^2.4.6
flutter:
  assets:
    - lib/shared/assets/images/
  fonts:
    - family: Mont-Bold
      fonts:
        - asset: lib/shared/assets/fonts/Mont-Bold.otf
    - family: Mont-SemiBold
      fonts:
        - asset: lib/shared/assets/fonts/Mont-SemiBold.otf
    - family: Mont-Heavy
      fonts:
        - asset: lib/shared/assets/fonts/Mont-Heavy.otf
uses-material-design: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with version `3.0.0-dev.4` of `riverpod_generator`, so temporarily you can strictly use `3.0.0-dev.3` by removing the `^`:

```yaml
dev_dependencies:
  riverpod_generator: 3.0.0-dev.3
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This solution worked fine.